# What is the meaning of "right back over my hill" in a poetic context?

Tags: meaning, poetry

> Before he was gone - right back over my hill
> Who now will find him?
> Why, nobody will
> Doom shall I bring to him, I that am queen
> Lost forever, nine by nineteen.

What is the meaning of *right back over my hill*?

Comment: Presumably it refers to someone going away over a hill ("right back" meaning leaving soon after he arrived), with "my hill" either meaning a hill on my property, or a hill near me (as in "my town", "my street", etc). But it helps to provide context on where this is from and what it's about.

Comment: This comes from https://finalproblem.tumblr.com/post/156312744365 and is a part of a poetic puzzle. It is not really a matter of English usage, more a matter of contrivance and opinion, I don't think it relates to English usage as normally handled in this site.